# Symfony2 links with CSRF token

Tags: php, symfony

I can't found a documentation about how to generate a link with the CSRF token, like in Symfony 1.4:

```
link_to(__('Delete'), url_for('ntw-delete', $network), array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?', 'method' => 'delete'))
```

**UPDATED:** I created a twig extension for that. Maybe it will help to someone

`src/UmbrellaWeb/Bundle/ExtraTwigBundle/Twig/LinkExtension.php`

```
<?php
namespace UmbrellaWeb\Bundle\ExtraTwigBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_Function_Method;
use Twig_Environment;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\CsrfProviderInterface;

class LinkExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    protected $csrfProvider;

    public function __construct(CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider)
    {
        $this->csrfProvider = $csrfProvider;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'link_to' => new Twig_Function_Method($this, 'linkToFunction', array(
                'is_safe' => array('html')
            ))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Build a link with anchor
     * 
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $title
     * @param array $options Available options: 
     *  string 'confirm' - Text for the popup
     *  string 'method' - HTTP Method: post, delete, put
     *  string 'csrfIntention' - CSRF intention. If empty then no CSRF. Not used for GET requests
     *  string 'csrfField' - CSRF field name. _token by default
     *  bool 'escape' - escape title, TRUE by default
     */
    public function linkToFunction($path,$title,array $options = array())
    {
        $default = array(
            'csrf_intention' => '',
            'csrf_field' => '_token',
            'escape' => TRUE
        );

        $options = array_merge($default,$options);

        $ecape = $options['escape'];
        unset($options['escape']);

        $return = '<a href="%s"%s>%s</a>';

        $return = sprintf($return,
            htmlspecialchars($path),
            $this->_tagOptions($this->_options2javascript($options)),
            ($ecape)?htmlspecialchars($title):$title
        );

        return $return;
    }

    function _options2javascript($options)
    {
        // confirm
        $confirm = isset($options['confirm']) ? $options['confirm'] : '';

        unset($options['confirm']);

        // method
        $method = isset($options['method']) ? $options['method'] : false;

        unset($options['method']);

        // CSRF Intention
        $csrfIntention = isset($options['csrf_intention']) ? $options['csrf_intention'] : false;

        unset($options['csrf_intention']);

        // CSRF field name
        $csrfField = isset($options['csrf_field']) ? $options['csrf_field'] : false;

        unset($options['csrf_field']);

        $onclick = isset($options['onclick']) ? $options['onclick'] : '';

        if ($confirm && $method)
        {
            $options['onclick'] = $onclick . 'if (' . $this->_confirmJsFunction($confirm) . ') { ' . $this->_methodJsFunction($method,$csrfIntention,$csrfField) . ' };return false;';
        } else 
            if ($confirm)
            {
                if ($onclick)
                {
                    $options['onclick'] = 'if (' . $this->_confirmJsFunction($confirm) . ') { return ' . $onclick . '} else return false;';
                } else
                {
                    $options['onclick'] = 'return ' . $this->_confirmJsFunction($confirm) . ';';
                }
            } else 
                if ($method)
                {
                    $options['onclick'] = $onclick . $this->_methodJsFunction($method,$csrfIntention,$csrfField) . 'return false;';
                }

        return $options;
    }

    function _confirmJsFunction($confirm)
    {
      return "confirm('".$this->_escapeJs($confirm)."')";
    }

    /**
     * Escape carrier returns and single and double quotes for Javascript segments.
     */
    function _escapeJs($javascript = '')
    {
        $javascript = preg_replace('/\r\n|\n|\r/', "\\n", $javascript);
        $javascript = preg_replace('/(["\'])/', '\\\\\1', $javascript);
        return $javascript;
    }

    function _methodJsFunction($method,$csrfIntention,$csrfField)
    {
        $function = "var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'post'; f.action = this.href;";

        //put, delete HTTP methods
        if ('post' != strtolower($method))
        {
            $function .= "var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); ";
            $function .= sprintf("m.setAttribute('name', '_method'); m.setAttribute('value', '%s'); f.appendChild(m);", strtolower($method));
        }

        // CSRF protection
        if ($csrfIntention)
        {
            /**
             * @todo isCsrfEnabled() - check a global config
             */
            if (TRUE)
            {
                $function .= "var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); ";
                $function .= sprintf("m.setAttribute('name', '%s'); m.setAttribute('value', '%s'); f.appendChild(m);", $csrfField, $this->csrfProvider->generateCsrfToken($csrfIntention));
            }
        }

        $function .= "f.submit();";
        return $function;
    }

    function _tagOptions(array $options = array())
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach ($options as $key => $value)
        {
            $html .= ' ' . $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '"';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'umbrellaweb_link';
    }
}
```

`services.xml`

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="umbrellaweb.twig.link_extension" class="UmbrellaWeb\Bundle\ExtraTwigBundle\Twig\LinkExtension">
            <tag name="twig.extension" />
            <argument type="service" id="form.csrf_provider" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Now in twig you can use:

```
{{ link_to(path('jk_aa_admin_delete',{'id' : admin.id}),'<img src="del_icon.png"/>',
{'escape':false,'method':'delete','csrf_intention':'delete-admin',
'confirm':'Are you sure?'}) }}
```

I controller:

```
//check CSRF token
if (FALSE === $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->isCsrfTokenValid('delete-admin', $request->get('_token')))
{
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Invalid CSRF token.');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem.  First I generated token in the Controller and passed to a twig file

```
 $intentions = 'unknown';  
 $csrfToken = $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken($intentions);

 return array('csrfToken'=>$csrfToken);
```

than from the twig file you can access the token as

```
var token = '{{csrfToken}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I accpet your answer. But my question is how to generate a link without passing a additional parameter to view? I already created a twig extension for that

Comment: you can then either make a form which has the token in a hidden field and links to your deleteAction while passing the token, or you can make an ajax request (if you dont want the user to be redirected) which contains the token

Answer (score 6):

Solution from **Symfony 4**, from documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html:

Twig template:

```
<a href="{{ path("remove", { "id" : 1, "csrf_token" : csrf_token('remove') }) }}">
{{ "remove" | trans }}
</a>
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/remove/{id}", name="dashboard_alert_remove")
 *
 * @ParamConverter("alert", class="App:Alert")
 *
 * @param Alert $alert
 */
public function doRemoveAction(Alert $alert, Request $request)
{
    $submittedToken = $request->get('csrf_token');

    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('remove', $submittedToken))
    {
        // Do the deletion stuff
    }
}
```