# How can I check whether the supplied CSRF token is invalid in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony, csrf, symfony-forms

I have created a Symfony2 form and bound it to the Request. I need to explicitly ensure whether the CSRF token is valid/invalid before proceeding with the rest of the form.

`$form['_token']->isValid()` throws `OutOfBoundsException` with message "Child _token does not exist."

I can still verify that the rendered form contains `_token` field. In case that CSRF value is invalid, `$form->isValid()` returns false.

What am I missing here?

---

Update 1:

Controller (partial):

```
private function buildTestForm() {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('name','text')
            ->getForm();
    return $form;
}

/**
 * @Route("/test/show_form", name="test.form.show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showFormTest()
{
    $form = $this->buildTestForm();
    return $this->render('TestBundle::form_test.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}

/**
 * @Route("/test/submit_form", name="test.form.submit")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function formTest()
{
    $form = $this->buildTestForm();
    $form->bind($this->getRequest());
    if ($form['_token']->isValid()) {
        return new Response('_token is valid');
    } else {
        return new Response('_token is invalid');
    }
}
```

Template

```
{# Twig template #}
<form action="{{ path('test.form.submit') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Test Form" />
</form>
```

Comment: you are missing at least the form code.

Comment: @mpm, true - now added full code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: CSRF Token validation is done automatically http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Comment: @artworkadシ yes, I am aware of that. The problem is that I need to react differently in case that _token is invalid. That is why I need to check it explicitly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no documented way to check csrf token manually. Symfony automatically validates the presence and accuracy of this token. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

However there is a csrf provider:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/SessionCsrfProvider.html

and

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/DefaultCsrfProvider.html

> Marks classes able to provide CSRF protection You can generate a CSRF
>   token by using the method generateCsrfToken(). To this method you
>   should pass a value that is unique to the page that should be secured
>   against CSRF attacks. This value doesn't necessarily have to be
>   secret. Implementations of this interface are responsible for adding
>   more secret information.
>
> If you want to secure a form submission against CSRF attacks, you
>   could supply an "intention" string. This way you make sure that the
>   form can only be bound to pages that are designed to handle the form,
>   that is, that use the same intention string to validate the CSRF token
>   with isCsrfTokenValid().

You can retrieve the provider like this

```
$csrf = $this->get('form.csrf_provider');
```

use can then use

```
public Boolean isCsrfTokenValid(string $intention, string $token)

Validates a CSRF token.
```

> Parameters string $intention  The intention used when generating the
>   CSRF token string $token  The token supplied by the browser
>
> Return Value Boolean  Whether the token supplied by the browser is
>   correct

You need to finde out the intention string used by  your form.

Some interesting posts on SO:

[Symfony CSRF and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054449/symfony-csrf-and-ajax)

[Symfony2 links with CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972318/symfony2-links-with-csrf-token)

Comment: Deprecated since Symfony 2.4, use ```security.csrf.token_manager``` instead. http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Csrf/CsrfTokenManagerInterface.html

Answer (score 11):

In addition to artworkad, you can specify an intention:

Twig:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="form_name[field]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('form_name') }}">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$token = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');
$csrf_token = new CsrfToken('form_name', $token);
var_dump($this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid($csrf_token));
```

---

Or not:

Twig:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('') }}">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$token = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');
$csrf_token = new CsrfToken('', $token);
var_dump($this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid($csrf_token));
```

Comment: Should ajax request regenerate the token?

Comment: You can regenerate the token in ajax and update your input value :


`public function tokenAction($intention)  { $csrf = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');  $token = $csrf->refreshToken($intention);  return new Response($token); }`

Answer (score 1):

Another way (if you prefer DI) to validate token outside of controller (e.g. in listener):

```
/** @var Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface */
private $csrfTokenManager;

public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager) 
{
    $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
}

public function isValid(): bool
{
    return $this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid(
            new CsrfToken('authenticate', $request->getRequest()->headers->get('X-CSRF-TOKEN'))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of this but have you tried the validator on an unmapped field:

```
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validatePropertyValue($entity, '_token', $form['_token']);
if (count($violations)) {
    // the property value is not valid
}
```