# Check if Token is Valid

Tags: php, rest, symfony, token

I am using third party REST API in my SYMFONY 4.3 app. My app requires checking if token is valid before any request. When is the best place to check if the token is valid and if not try to refresh before request in symfony? Any before request filter in symfony exists? or is there global object when I can fetch all request and if  header is 401 I can perform specific action

Now I have central point in my app and all requests are passed through this function. But in future when I will have other request not passed through this function I have to make next function etc... and I am searching place where put isTokenValid code, I am thining about place like " call this function before any request to API "

Should i Use it?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#token-validation-example

```
public function prepareRequest($method, $endPoint) {
.........

// Users can have many tokens connected to different accounts on third party app
 $apiTokens = $user->getApiTokens();

 /** @var ApiToken $apiToken */
 foreach ($apiTokens as $apiToken) {
    if ($this->isTokenValid($apiToken)) {
       ............. make request with specifed apiToken
}


 public function isTokenValid(ApiToken $token): bool
{
  if token is not valid return false
  if token date expired try to refresh token
  if token is not valid or refreshing token fails return false else return true

}
```

Comment: Please Add some codes and let us know what you have tried already! and check if this is your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044408/how-can-i-check-whether-the-supplied-csrf-token-is-invalid-in-symfony2

Comment: It's not, I mean validate JWT token before request to API, not csrf token

Answer (score 2):

The solution I'd like to suggest is to use [lexik/jwt-bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) I use it in almost all of mine front-end authentication projects for example you can customize the default response (JWT token not found / not valid) to return the response you desire. You can create both anonymous true or false routes for your purpose I guess anonymous should be true even though your token expired you will extend its lifetime. In case you want some insights put a comment to this answer and I'll provide as best as I can

Comment: I can vouch for JWT, I have used this in a couple of enterprise projects, it is very good.